# How to list the quantity of files per subdir on Unix

Tags: unix

I have 60 subdirs in a directory, example name of the directory: test/queues.

The subdirs:

```
test/queues/subdir1
test/queues/subdir2
test/queues/subdir3

(...)

test/queues/subdir60
```

I want a command that gives me the output of the number of files in each subdirectory, listed separately, example:

```
test/queues/subdir1 - 45 files
test/queues/subdir2 - 76 files
test/queues/subdir3 - 950 files

(...)

test/queues/subdir60 - 213 files
```

Through my researchs, I only got the command `ls -lat test/queues/* | wc -l`, but this command outputs me the total of files in all of these subdirs. For example, It returns me only 4587, that is the total number of files in all these 60 subdirs. I want the output listing separately, the quantity of files in each folder.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Do you also want the number of entries in 'test/queues/subdir1/subdir11`?  Or do you want to restrict your output to one level deep?

Comment: Do you want the number of all names in the directory, or only those entries which refer to a regular file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a loop to count the lines for every subdirectory individually:

```
for d in test/queues/*/
do
   echo "$d" - $(ls -lat "$d" | wc -l)
done
```

Note that the output of `ls -lat some_directory` will contain a few additional lines like

```
total 123
drwxr-xr-x 1 user group     0 Feb 26 09:51 ../
drwxr-xr-x 1 user group     0 Jan 25 12:35 ./
```

If your `ls` command supports these options you can use

```
for d in test/queues/*/
do
   echo "$d" - $(ls -A1 "$d" | wc -l)
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `ls | wc -l` in a loop to all subdirs

```
for x in *; do echo "$x => $(ls $x | wc -l)"; done;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict the output to directories that are one level deep and you only want a count of regular files, you could do:

```
find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -exec sh -c '
    printf "%s\t" "$0"; find "$0" -type f -maxdepth 1 | wc -l' {} \; \
    | column -t
```

You can get the "name - %d files" format with:

```
find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -exec sh -c '
    printf "%s - %d files\n" "$0" \
    "$(find "$0" -type f -maxdepth 1 | wc -l)"' {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using find and awk:

```
find test/queues -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -printf "%h\n" | awk '{ map[$0]++ } END { for (i in map) { print i" - "map[i]} }'
```

Use maxdepth and mindepth to ensure that we are only searching the directory structure one level down. Print only the leading directories thorough printf "%h" Pipe the output into awk and create an incrementing map array with the directories as the index. At the end, loop through the map array printing the directories and the counts.

On Unix in the case of not -printf option with find, use exec dirname instead:

```
find test/queues -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -exec dirname {} \; | awk '{ map[$0]++ } END { for (i in map) { print i" - "map[i]} }'
```